# Appeding summary row of total for each factor level

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, tidyverse

**Required Output**

This is the required output (numbers may be different).

```
 City      Res       Pop  Pop1

  Total          4503739  4455
  State    Urban 3003948  2966
  State    Rural 1499791  1489

  Total          1000915   986
  A        Urban  500414   493
  A        Rural  500501   494

  Total           999938   1009
  B        Urban  499922   497
  B        Rural  500016   512

  Total          1000912  976
  C       Urban  501638   493
  C       Rural  499274   483
```

`R` code is

```
City <- rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 2) 
Res  <- factor(rep(c("Urban", "Rural"), times = length(City)/2))
set.seed(12345)
Pop  <- rpois(n = length(City), lambda = 500000)
Pop1 <- rpois(n = length(City), lambda = 500)
df   <- data.frame(City, Res, Pop, Pop1)
df

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Res) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(City = "State") %>% 
  bind_rows(df) %>% 
  select(City, everything()) %>% 
  ungroup(Res) %>% 
  group_by(., City) %>%
  bind_rows(
        group_by(., Res) %>%
        summarise(Pop = sum(Pop), Pop1 = sum(Pop1)),
        . ) %>% 
  select(City, everything())


# A tibble: 10 x 4
   City  Res       Pop  Pop1
   <chr> <fct>   <int> <int>
 1 NA    Rural 2999582  2978
 2 NA    Urban 3003948  2966
 3 State Rural 1499791  1489
 4 State Urban 1501974  1483
 5 A     Urban  500414   493
 6 A     Rural  500501   494
 7 B     Urban  499922   497
 8 B     Rural  500016   512
 9 C     Urban  501638   493
10 C     Rural  499274   483
```

I wonder how to get the required output more efficiently. Thanks

**sessionInfo**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.4.0        stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_0.8.1         
[4] purrr_0.3.2          readr_1.3.1          tidyr_0.8.3.9000    
[7] tibble_2.1.1         ggplot2_3.1.1        tidyverse_1.2.1.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.4.0     compiler_3.6.0  
 [5] dbplyr_1.4.0     plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.6.0      zeallot_0.1.0   
 [9] lubridate_1.7.4  jsonlite_1.6     nlme_3.1-140     gtable_0.3.0    
[13] lattice_0.20-38  pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.4.9003 reprex_0.3.0    
[17] cli_1.1.0        DBI_1.0.0        rstudioapi_0.10  haven_2.1.0     
[21] withr_2.1.2      xml2_1.2.0.9000  httr_1.4.0       fs_1.3.1        
[25] generics_0.0.2   vctrs_0.1.0.9003 hms_0.4.2        grid_3.6.0      
[29] tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.1       R6_2.4.0         fansi_0.4.0     
[33] readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.4     magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.4 
[37] scales_1.0.0     rvest_0.3.4      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1
[41] utf8_1.1.4       stringi_1.4.3    lazyeval_0.2.2   munsell_0.5.0   
[45] broom_0.5.2      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah for your interest in my problem. I restarted `R` and not getting any error. Please see my `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: IN your output, there is `NA` in place of `Total` (by running the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option based on `purrr::map_df` and `split`. We can `split` df using *City* then loop through each *City*: bind at the top of each City a row *Total* which sum `Pop` and `Pop1`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
  group_by(Res) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(Res= factor(Res, levels=c('Urban','Rural'))) %>%
  mutate(City = "State") %>% 
  bind_rows(df) %>% 
  mutate(City=factor(City, levels = c('State','A','B','C'))) %>% 
  split(.$City) %>% 
  map_df(., ~bind_rows(summarise_if(.x,is.numeric, sum) %>% mutate(City='Total', Res=''), 
                       .x %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)) %>% 
  select(City, Res, Pop, Pop1))


# A tibble: 12 x 4
   City  Res       Pop  Pop1
  <chr> <chr>   <int> <int>
1 Total ""    3001765  2972
2 State Urban 1501974  1483
3 State Rural 1499791  1489
4 Total ""    1000915   987
5 A     Urban  500414   493
6 A     Rural  500501   494
7 Total ""     999938  1009
8 B     Urban  499922   497
9 B     Rural  500016   512
10 Total ""    1000912   976
11 C     Urban  501638   493
12 C     Rural  499274   483
```

Comment: The column `Res` is not sorted properly.

Comment: @MYaseen208 yes, `summarise_if` ignore the levels of `Res` and sort `Res` alphabetically, we can use `arrange`, see my update.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  select(Res, Pop, Pop1) %>%
  group_by(Res) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  mutate(City = fct_explicit_na(City, "State")) %>%  # from forcats: renames NA as factor
  select(City, Res, Pop, Pop1)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  City  Res       Pop  Pop1
  <fct> <fct>   <int> <int>
1 State Rural 1499791  1489
2 State Urban 1501974  1483
3 A     Urban  500414   493
4 A     Rural  500501   494
5 B     Urban  499922   497
6 B     Rural  500016   512
7 C     Urban  501638   493
8 C     Rural  499274   483
```

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring for your answer. However, your code does not provide totals for each City and State. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: I don't understand. You have three cities, each with a Rural and Urban total around 500k. Then you have Statewide totals that are the sum of all Rural and all Urban, respectively, which we should expect to be around 1.5M. In your question it looks like you accidentally doubled the total for Urban, and in your code output you have an extra row for each of Urban and Rural, which add the statewide total to the detail, showing 2x the statewide total. When you say "totals for each City," are you looking to add numbers into the blank Total rows in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `add_row`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_split(Res) %>%
   map_df(~ add_row(., City = "State", Res = first(.$Res), 
          Pop = sum(.$Pop), Pop1 = sum(.$Pop1)) %>% 
           add_row(., City = 'Total', Res = first(.$Res), 
          Pop = sum(.$Pop), Pop1 = sum(.$Pop1)))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   City  Res       Pop  Pop1
#   <fct> <fct>   <int> <int>
# 1 A     Rural  500501   494
# 2 B     Rural  500016   512
# 3 C     Rural  499274   483
# 4 State Rural 1499791  1489
# 5 Total Rural 2999582  2978
# 6 A     Urban  500414   493
# 7 B     Urban  499922   497
# 8 C     Urban  501638   493
# 9 State Urban 1501974  1483
#10 Total Urban 3003948  2966
```

---

Or another option is `rollup` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
f1 <- function(dat), rollup(dat, lapply(.SD, sum), by = "Res",
       .SDcols = Pop:Pop1)
setDT(df)
out1 <- rbind(f1(df)[-.N][, City := "State"], df)
rbind(f1(out1)[-.N][, City := "Total"], out1)
```